# Get Uri from CameraCaptureTask or PhotoChooserTask Using OriginalFilename

Tags: windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, cameracapturetask

In Windows Phone 8, I want to persist the location of a picture returned by either the CameraCaptureTask or the PhotoChooserTask. They have the same API so any answer which matches one of them works on both. When delivering an image, they deliver both a stream and an `OriginalFilename` string. Is it possible to persist theOriginalFilename and later use it to retrieve the image, either by `Uri` or through the `MediaLibrary` (assuming the user didn't delete it)?

According to a remark at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680266%28v=pandp.11%29.aspx) the way to do this was broken 2 years ago, and the only way to achieve this was by making a copy of the image in isolated storage and to refer to the copy. There have been one major and 3 minor OS revisions since then, so I don't trust that information to be up to date.